# run flutter got a error the 'attrib' switch other project same error

Tags: flutter

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
'attrib'��(��) ���� �Ǵ� �ܺ� ����, ������ �� �ִ� ���α׷�, �Ǵ�
��ġ ������ �ƴմϴ�.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\WD\Desktop\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 945

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.


flutter.gradle that line


 doLast {
                    project.exec {`your text`
                        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                            commandLine('cmd', '/c', "attrib -r ${assetsDirectory}/* /s")
                        } else {
                            commandLine('chmod', '-R', 'u+w', assetsDirectory)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

i cant understand this contant

Comment: Are you new to flutter or have you been using this project and suddenly this error shows up?

Answer (score 1):

The message you are getting is related to the permission. Running your project as Administrator might solve this.

1. If you are using a terminal you can do it by right-clicking on the terminal icon and selecting **Run as administrator**.
2. You can also change the permission by:
   Go to the **Properties** of your project's directory. Then go to **Security** and then click on **Edit**

Link - [Establishing Windows File and Folder Level Permissions](https://www.uwec.edu/kb/article/drives-establishing-windows-file-and-folder-level-permissions/)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @최경민 have you created assets directory in your project?